# Heroku rails 4 + puma deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, puma

I have being trying to deploy my rails 4 app to heroku and use Puma. The puma configuration I have used from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#adding-puma-to-your-application

But still I am getting error. Please let me know what changes to do to make it work. Error is

```
> 2016-04-15T02:37:43.118777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-04-15T02:37:43.118406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2016-04-15T02:37:45.374269+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2016-04-15T02:37:47.238844+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2016-04-15T02:37:47.238871+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Version 3.3.0 (ruby 2.2.4-p230), codename: Jovial Platypus
2016-04-15T02:37:47.238872+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2016-04-15T02:37:47.238880+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Process workers: 2
2016-04-15T02:37:47.238879+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Environment: production
2016-04-15T02:37:47.238880+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Preloading application
2016-04-15T02:37:49.185177+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:14560
2016-04-15T02:37:49.185334+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2016-04-15T02:37:49.189100+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 0 (pid: 6) booted, phase: 0
2016-04-15T02:37:49.190620+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 1 (pid: 10) booted, phase: 0
2016-04-15T02:37:49.338111+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-04-15T02:37:51.250717+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=vna-web.herokuapp.com request_id=69b23803-e2c4-4915-adef-d9358590c11f fwd="116.75.138.168" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=79ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-04-15T02:37:51.568588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vna-web.herokuapp.com request_id=ff467b63-8cbc-4a5e-ab93-e8d87020cdf2 fwd="116.75.138.168" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=143
2016-04-15T02:37:59.640100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-04-15T02:37:59.640965+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-04-15T02:37:59.523049+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 2ffe40b by saurabh@toptal.com
2016-04-15T02:37:59.523049+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v19 created by saurabh@toptal.com
2016-04-15T02:37:59.706827+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-04-15T02:37:59.706838+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-04-15T02:38:01.362522+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-04-15T02:38:01.726315+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
2016-04-15T02:38:01.838999+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] === puma shutdown: 2016-04-15 02:38:01 +0000 ===
2016-04-15T02:38:01.839020+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Goodbye!
2016-04-15T02:38:02.019288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2016-04-15T02:38:02.645079+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-04-15T02:38:03.855263+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2016-04-15T02:38:03.855304+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.3.0 (ruby 2.2.4-p230), codename: Jovial Platypus
2016-04-15T02:38:03.855306+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 1, max threads: 16
2016-04-15T02:38:03.855307+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2016-04-15T02:38:05.694384+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:10578
2016-04-15T02:38:05.694550+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2016-04-15T02:38:05.829089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-04-15T02:38:11.021955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=vna-web.herokuapp.com request_id=705c318d-1856-4378-bc8b-de9727a887c1 fwd="116.75.138.168" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=71ms status=500 bytes=1669
```

Below is Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Puma config file at config/puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-  
  # applications-   with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I even tried to deploy by removing puma, thinking it would run on webrick, but still puma error were getting thrown.

Comment: what kind an error u getting ? Pls post your gem file too.

Comment: Upload your error detail.

Comment: Updated the question with the error log.

Answer (score 0):

The error was not with Puma. The error got resolved after executing

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I refereed https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4